# How to update dependent table in Entity Framework in TPT mapping

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-5, table-per-type

I have this model:

```
public class Person
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}

public class Student : Person
{
    public string Code { get; set; }
}
```

and this context:

```
public class Context : DbContext
{
    public Context()
        : base("Context")
    {
        Database.SetInitializer<Context>(null);
    }

    public DbSet<Student> Students { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Person>().ToTable("People");
        modelBuilder.Entity<Student>().ToTable("Students");
    }
}
```

And I want to be able to insert an instance of `Student` without code first, and then later at some future point, I want to update that `Student`'s code. Here is a simple code explanation:

```
var student = new Student
{
    FirstName = "Saeed",
    LastName = "Nemati",
};
using (var context = new Context())
{
    context.Students.Add(student);
    context.SaveChanges();
}

// A month later I want to update the code
var student2 = new Student
{
    Id = student.Id,
    Code = "something"
};
using (var context = new Context())
{
    context.Students.Attach(student2);
    context.Entry(student2).State = EntityState.Modified;
    context.SaveChanges();
}
```

The problem is, EF complaints that `FirstName` and `LastName` should be provided and can't be null. I can populate `Student` inherited properties from `Person` properties, but this sounds smelly. Is there any approach or technique in EF to update the derived class (dependent table) in isolation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is simple.When you modify state `student2` entity framework thinks `FirstName` and `LastName` are null.
Instead using:

```
context.Entry(student2).State = EntityState.Modified;
```

You should change `Property`:

```
context.Entry(student2).Property(x => x.Code).IsModified = true;
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
using (var context = new Context())
{
    var student2 = context.Students.SingleOrDefault(x=>x.Id == yourID);

    student2.Code = "Something";

    context.Students.Attach(student2);
    context.Entry(student2).State = EntityState.Modified;
    context.SaveChanges();
}
```

Comment: Good solution @BappiDatta. But what if the derived class has more than 20 properties. In that case, I should copy those properties from the `Student` taken from database, and paste them in the target `Student`.